# How can I mock the getPdo method of the DB facade in Laravel Unit Testing?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

After taking on a project that is eager loading so much that it causes infinite loops in some effected areas, as a need for speed, some of the SQL was written through the `getPdo` method.

I now want to write Unit Tests for the associated changed areas and thus Mock the `getPdo` to point at the in memory SQLite. I am writing a short test to just see if I can mock the `getPdo` method succesfully by just asserting that I have a table `my_table` which has no results.

```
(new \PDO('sqlite::memory:'))->exec('CREATE TABLE my_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)');

$mock = Mockery::mock('alias:Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB');
$mock->shouldReceive('connection')
    ->andReturnSelf();

$mock->connection()->shouldReceive('getPdo')
    ->andReturnUsing(function () {
        return new \PDO('sqlite::memory:');
    });

DB::swap($mock);

$stmt = DB::connection()->getPdo()->prepare('select * from my_table');
$stmt->execute();
$this->assertEquals([], $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
```

Running this test is giving me the following error which I cannot seem to understand:

> Static method Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::swap() does not exist on this mock object

I am using Laravel 8.8X.X and usually, the `DB::swap` works perfectly fine when changing the underlying interface. How can I get around this?

Update:

Using the built in mocks as suggested, it doesn't find my table.

```
DB::shouldReceive('connection->getPdo')
    ->andReturnUsing(function () {
        return new \PDO('sqlite::memory:');
});
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: my_table

Update 2:

Mocking the `Connection` fixes the `swap` issue but I still cannot see my table during a SQL statement:

```
(new \PDO('sqlite::memory:'))->exec('CREATE TABLE my_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)');

$connection = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Database\Connection');
$connection->shouldReceive('connection')->andReturnSelf();
$connection->connection()->shouldReceive('getPdo')
    ->andReturnUsing(fn() => new \PDO('sqlite::memory:'));

DB::swap($connection);

$stmt = DB::connection()->getPdo()->prepare('select * from my_table');
$stmt->execute();
$this->assertEquals([], $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: my_table

Strangely, if I check if the mock is successful by doing:

```
$connection->connection()->shouldReceive('getPdo')->andReturnUsing(fn() => []);
$this->assertEquals([], DB::connection()->getPdo());
```

I get a passed test. Putting it back and doing more debug, The `exec` seems to be returning `0` when creating the table?

Comment: You don't have to mock facades, the idea of using facades is exactly that you can mock them instantly using `Facade::fake()` or `DB::shouldReceive(...)`, etc. Read [how to mock facades](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#mocking-facades) as there is an entire section in the documentation about it... Also, you should not need to mock `DB`, because you should not be using `DB` but a model. So that is a code smell. Check my stackoverflow profile to see more examples of how to test

Comment: Inside of `Update 1` I tried to do this but the table is not found when I then go to query it. As mentioned in the question, its a large project and changing the calling models would break a tonne of functionality that rely on said eager loads/serialization calls so a decision was made to migrate the areas crashing/exhausting memory until `DB` calls. Typically, logic would be seperated from RW data operations but I'm left with no choice but to try and just mock up a in memory SQLLite table to write tests for these. I appreciate the advice on your profile and will add it to my further reading

Comment: Can't you try using `DB::shouldReceive('the mocked method')->andReturn('your desired value')`? Forget about the `DB::swap`, the `mock`, etc, just plain that

Answer (score 1):

You are mocking the wrong class.

Laravel's facades are static wrappers around an instance of some class, in this case a database connection. In your test, you are replacing the entire static Facade with a mock:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('alias:Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB');
```

Then later, you ask *that mock Facade* to swap out its underlying instance:

```
DB::swap($mock);
```

The mock class has no definition for "swap", so the mocking library complains.

What you wanted to do instead was mock *the database connection itself*, then tell the *real* Facade to use that as its instance. I don't have a Laravel project to hand to test, but I believe this is the right class:

```
$mockConnection = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Database\Connection');
// Note that this is the real DB class, not a mock!
DB::swap($mockConnection);
```

There are also [built-in helpers for mocking facades](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#mocking-facades).

Comment: Is there any simple way to do that? Or I can I just use `$this->app->instance` and replace the entire `DB` facade with the `$mock`?

Comment: @Jaquarh I was just looking up the right class name; I've added an example, it may not be quite right, but hopefully illustrates what I'm saying. You do *not* want to replace the Facade with a mock, you want to *use* the Facade to *make use of* your mock.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, I've attempted this and you was 100% right about it being the wrong class and that now makes sense looking at it. I've updated my question with both of your suggest methods, it seems none of them are working as expected but a great result to see a different error after a long time looking at this lol